# Verify that current user owns the requesting project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am pretty sure I want to use middleware here, but not sure how. I have a controller called `AssetController`.

Users upload files to their own projects. I have functions in the controller that can create a new asset, edit an existing and delete an asset. Right now inside each of those respective functions I check if the requesting user actually owns that project using this code (I pass the `project_id` to every request):

```
<?php
public function destroy($id)
{
  $project = Projects::find(Input::get('pid'));
  //-- if $project exists and the user_id row is equal to the authenticated user id, let them proceeed
  if ($project && $project->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
  {
    //-- user owns the project so continue to delete asset with id of $id
  }
  //-- else, invalid project id because this user does not own it
}
```

So rather than using that if block in every function, how would I use middleware (if that is even what I am supposed to use) to do this check before continuing to the actual function I want to call.

Right now my `__construct()` function just has this:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of middleware or `if` conditionals, you can include it in your query:

```php
$project = Projects::where('user_id ', auth()->id())->findOrFail(Input::get('pid'));
```

The [`findOrFail`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method will automatically return with a 404 if the model is not found.

---

If you use this a lot, you can add it as a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes):

```php
class Projects extends Model
{
    public function scopeOwnedBy($query, $user)
    {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
    }
}
```

you can then use it in your controllers easily:

```php
$project = Projects::ownedBy(auth()->user())->findOrFail(Input::get('pid'));
```

which makes it a little clearer what you're doing.

Comment: Rad, was not aware of this function! Ok, so that eliminates the `if` block. What if I didn't want to include that line in my functions at all? Would that be a job for middleware? I am trying to reduce redundancy.

Comment: @Ronnie - there are technically other ways to do this, both via a middleware and via the new [authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization) system, but for your simple example I believe what I've shown you is enough. You can add the query scope if you want, but more than that might be overkill for something this simple.